# Button sending same object in both mouse down and mouse up event

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I created 2 button in WPF window and also added mouse down and mouse up event for both buttons. I did mouse down on one button and mouse up on second. but i am getting same first button object to event handler in both events. My question is why i am not getting the second button object in mouse up event.

This is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MouseDownUpSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="but1" Content="source" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseUp" />
    <Button x:Name="but2" Content="destination" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="406,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_MouseUp"/>

</Grid>
```

Code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string source = null;
    string destination = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Button src=sender as Button;
        source = src.Content as string;

    }

    private void Button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Button src = sender as Button;
        destination = src.Content as string;

        if(destination.Equals(source))
        {

        }
    }
```

I am trying to transfer data from one object to another through drag & drop

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looks like XY problem.

Comment: @Dennis probably creating the most unintuitive UI concepts ... or some weird form of custom "drag & drop" ...

Comment: instead of this why not use click event?

Comment: Actually I want to transfer data from one object to another. Now I understood I can achieve this through WPF Drag & Drop using DragDropEffects.Copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why i am not getting the second button object in mouse up event.

Because this is how buttons work.

Taken from MSDN:

> If a mouse button is pressed while the pointer is over a form or control, that object "captures" the mouse and receives all mouse events up to and including the last MouseUp event.

This might also interest you:

> If mouse buttons are pressed in succession, the object that captures the mouse after the first press receives all mouse events until all buttons are released.

Comment: there is no possibility for `MouseDown` event by `button1` and `MouseUp` event by `button2` and wise versa. these are sequential events

Comment: Yes ... if that was a question, as you basically repeated what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

[`Mouse.MouseDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) occurs when any mouse button is pressed, where as [`Mouse.MouseUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) occurs when any mouse button is released. So when you click a button `MouseUp` event is always followed by `MouseDown` event since they are sequential events. Hence your `if()` condition is always `true` in this case.

```
if(destination.Equals(source))
{
    //always executed;
}
```

Comment: `a button MouseUp event is always followed by MouseDown event` ... what?

Comment: means, When you click on a button `MouseDown` event is triggered and then `MouseUp` event is triggered, these are sequential event not separate events.

Comment: Well, then write it like that. What you have posted doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal through WPF drag & drop using DragDropEffects.Copy

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MouseDownUpSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="but1" Content="source" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" PreviewMouseMove="but_MouseMove" AllowDrop="True"   PreviewDrop="but_Drop" />
    <Button x:Name="but2" Content="destination" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="406,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" PreviewMouseMove="but_MouseMove" AllowDrop="True"   PreviewDrop="but_Drop"/>

</Grid>
```

CODE

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void but_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button src=sender as Button;
        if (src != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(src,
                                 src.Content.ToString(),
                                 DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    private void but_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        Button dest = sender as Button;
        string destinationContent = null; 
        destinationContent = dest.Content as string;

        if (dest != null)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
            {
                string sourceContent = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

                if (destinationContent.Equals(sourceContent))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("equal");
                }
            }
        }

    }



}
```